# Write "special characters" such as "%" in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, url, nsstring, character

Here's the problem... I need to put together some `NSStrings` using special characters like "%" or "&". Now here's the code I'm using even though the "%" doesn't show at all:

```
-(void)getPostingURL:(NSString*)path variablesNames:(NSArray*)names{
    NSString *result = path;
    for (int i=0; i<names.count; i++){
        result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?%@=&@&",result,names[i]];
    }
    NSLog(result);
}
```

This is the result I'd like to get:
call

```
[self getPostingURL:@"http://www.myurl.com/middleInteractionPost.php" variablesNames:@[@"name",@"state",@"language"]];
```

final string

```
http://www.myurl.com/middleInteractionPost.php?name=%@&state=%@&language=%@
```

Comment: I hope so, because I just build a solution for it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
-(void)getPostingURL:(NSString*)path variablesNames:(NSArray *)names
{
    NSString *result = path;
    result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"?"];
    for (NSString *variableName in names){
       NSString *stringToAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@=%%@", variableName];
       result = [result stringByAppendingString:stringToAppend];

       if (![variableName isEqual:[names lastObject]]) {
           result = [result stringByAppendingString:@"&"];
       }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", result);
}
```

It will construct and print this string:

`http://www.myurl.com/middleInteractionPost.php?name=%@&state=%@&language=%@`

Comment: sorry, there is a mistake, the question mark is missing, one second!

Answer (score 3):

The escape code for a percent sign is "%%", so your code should be replaced with "%%" where you want to show "%".